# Get position from depth texture

Tags: three.js

Im trying to reduce the number of post process textures I have to draw in my scene. The end goal is to support an SSAO shader. The shader requires depth, postion and normal data. Currently I am storing the depth and normals in 1 float texture and the position in another.

I've been doing some reading, and it seems possible that you can get the position by simply using the depth stored in the normal texture. You have to unproject the x and y and multiply it by the depth value. I can't seem to get this right however and its probably due to my lack of understanding...

So currently my positions are drawn to a position texture. This is what it looks like (this is currently working correctly)
[image: drawing position to texture]

So is my new method. I pass the normal texture that stores the normal x,y and z in the RGB channels and the depth in the w. In the SSAO shader I need to get the position and so this is how im doing it:

```
//viewport is a vec2 of the viewport width and height
//invProj is a mat4 using camera.projectionMatrixInverse (camera.projectionMatrixInverse.getInverse( camera.projectionMatrix );)

vec3 get_eye_normal()
{
    vec2 frag_coord = gl_FragCoord.xy/viewport;
    frag_coord = (frag_coord-0.5)*2.0;
    vec4 device_normal = vec4(frag_coord, 0.0, 1.0);
    return normalize((invProj * device_normal).xyz);
}

...

float srcDepth = texture2D(tNormalsTex, vUv).w;
vec3 eye_ray = get_eye_normal();
vec3 srcPosition = vec3( eye_ray.x * srcDepth , eye_ray.y * srcDepth , eye_ray.z * srcDepth );

//Previously was doing this:
//vec3 srcPosition = texture2D(tPositionTex, vUv).xyz;
```

However when I render out the positions it looks like this:

[image: Not the same - causing problems]

The SSAO looks very messed up using the new method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Mat, have you read this 3-piece descriptive tutorial ? If not, i guess this is what you will have to do right now :D 
http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reconstructing-position-from-depth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this. You need to multiply the ray normal by the camera far - near (I was using the normalized depth value - but you need the world depth value.)

I created a function to extract the position from the normal/depth texture like so:

First in the depth capture pass (fragment shader)

```
float ld = length(vPosition) / linearDepth; //linearDepth is cam.far - cam.near
gl_FragColor = vec4( normalize( vNormal ).xyz, ld );
```

And now in the shader trying to extract the position...

```
/// <summary>
/// This function will get the 3d world position from the Normal texture containing depth in its w component
/// <summary>
vec3 get_world_pos( vec2 uv )
{
    vec2 frag_coord = uv;   
    float depth = texture2D(tNormals, frag_coord).w;    
    float unprojDepth = depth * linearDepth - 1.0;      
    frag_coord = (frag_coord-0.5)*2.0;
    vec4 device_normal = vec4(frag_coord, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 eye_ray = normalize((invProj * device_normal).xyz);
    vec3 pos = vec3( eye_ray.x * unprojDepth, eye_ray.y * unprojDepth, eye_ray.z * unprojDepth );
    return pos;
}
```